# Is there a way to parse multiple lines to a single line by merging duplicates and tabbing non-duplicates?

Tags: text-processing, command-line-arguments

I'm having trouble formatting a list like this:

Problem:

```
XYZ gene1
XYZ gene2
GHE ATG01
GHE ATG02
```

Goal(tab-delimited spaces):

```
XYZ gene1 gene2
GHE ATG01 ATG02
```

I tried `ruby -F -ane '$F[1].split(/\t/).each {|x|print [$F [0],x,$F[2]]*"\t"`, `xargs`, and `paste` commands, but then got stuck figuring out how it would work, and that the ruby command is to make multiple lines, not single lines. I'm also new to command line text processing.

This is what I'm actually dealing with (and some more):

```
14-3-3 proteins AT1G22300
14-3-3 proteins AT1G26480
14-3-3 proteins AT1G34760
14-3-3 proteins AT1G35160
ZIK subfamily AT1G64630
ZIK subfamily AT3G04910
ZIK subfamily AT3G18750
```

And I wish to get this:

```
14-3-3 proteins AT1G22300 AT1G26480 AT1G34760 AT1G35160
ZIK subfamily AT1G64630 AT3G04910 AT3G18750
```

This is what I get:

```
xargs -a <some_file> | sed 's/ /,/g'
14-3-3,proteins,AT1G22300,14-3-3,proteins,AT1G26480,14-3-3,proteins,AT1G34760,14-3-3,proteins,AT1G35160,14-3-3,proteins,AT1G78220,14-3-3,proteins,AT1G78300,14-3-3,proteins,AT2G42590,14-3-3,proteins,AT3G02520,14-3-3,proteins
```

Answer (score 1):

With miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0)

```
mlr --nidx --ofs "\t" nest --nested-fs " " --implode --values --across-records -f 3 input.csv
```

You have (tab as field separator, space as field separator for nested values)

```
14-3-3  proteins        AT1G22300 AT1G26480 AT1G34760 AT1G35160
ZIK     subfamily       AT1G64630 AT3G04910 AT3G18750
```

As input I have used this one (space delimited)

```
14-3-3 proteins AT1G22300
14-3-3 proteins AT1G26480
14-3-3 proteins AT1G34760
14-3-3 proteins AT1G35160
ZIK subfamily AT1G64630
ZIK subfamily AT3G04910
ZIK subfamily AT3G18750
```